How to change line spacing in a multiline JButton
Since multiline buttons can be created with html text, I tried html's line-height attribute with decimal, pixel and percentage values to change the vertical line spacing. But in vain.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LineSpacing extends JFrame {
  public static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

  public LineSpacing() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(480, 240);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    add(createBox("Decimal", new String[]{"0.8", "0.9", "1.1"}));
    add(createBox("px", new String[]{"10px", "12px", "15px"}));
    add(createBox("%", new String[]{"85%", "95%", "110%"}));
    setVisible(true);
  }


  static public void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(LineSpacing::new);
  }


  private Box createBox(String header, String[] values) {
    Box box= Box.createVerticalBox();
    JPanel p= new JPanel();
    p.add(new JLabel(header, SwingConstants.CENTER));
    box.add(p);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      JButton b= new JButton("<html><center><span style='line-height:"+
        values[i]+"'>First line<br>and the second</span></html>");
      b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 40));
      b.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
      box.add(b);
    }
    return box;
  }

}


EDIT
Thanks to Dewmith Mihisara for his code below.
I modified his LineHeightButton class to get the overprinting fixed.
  add(createBox("Decimal", new Dimension(130, 40),
            new int[]{-1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6}));
.
.
    private Box createBox(String header, Dimension dim, int[] spacings) {
.
.
    JButton b = new LineHeightButton("First line\nand the second",
                                     dim, spacing);
====================================================

class LineHeightButton extends JButton {
    private final int lineSpacing;
    String text;

    public LineHeightButton(String text, Dimension dim, int lineSpacing) {
        super();
        this.lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
        this.text= text;
        setPreferredSize(dim);
        setMinimumSize(dim);
        setMaximumSize(dim);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setFont(getFont());
        String[] lines = text.split("\n");
        int i= 0, y = 15;
        for (String line : lines) {
            g2.drawString(line, getInsets().left,
                y += i*(g2.getFontMetrics().getHeight()-5 + lineSpacing));
            i++;
        }
    }
}

Remains the centering to be done, but that was not the problem.

That's not an HTML feature. It's CSS. So if it's supported at all, it will have to be in the context of <style> tags

If I'm not mistaken, Swing only supports HTML 3.2 and I believe not fully.

At least the sample code works with other properties, e.g. font-weight. However, I found in javax.swing.text.html.CSS that line-height is modeled, but not rendered. So there is currently no hope to get the line spacing modified with html.

Swing's HTML support is based on a subset of HTML 3.2, and it does not fully support CSS style, which includes the line-height property in all forms.
The line-height property might work with relative or percentage values if the HTML rendering engine in Swing recognizes it. However, since it's not working as intended, consider these workarounds:
Replace the <span> element with a <div> and set the line-height there. Sometimes, div elements with line-height are rendered better.

JButton b = new JButton("<html><center><div style='line-height:" +
    values[i] + "'>First line<br>and the second</div></html>");


If the line-height property still doesn't work, use explicit spacing methods, such as padding or adding <br> tags with inline font-size.
Instead of relying on HTML styling, adjust the text rendering yourself using a custom JButton or a JLabel with multiline support.
Example :
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LineSpacingCustom extends JFrame {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

    public LineSpacingCustom() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(480, 240);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(createBox("Decimal", new float[]{0.8f, 0.9f, 1.1f}));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(LineSpacingCustom::new);
    }

    private Box createBox(String header, float[] spacings) {
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JLabel(header, SwingConstants.CENTER));
        box.add(p);

        for (float spacing : spacings) {
            JButton b = new LineHeightButton("First line\nand the second", spacing);
            b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));
            box.add(b);
        }
        return box;
    }
}

class LineHeightButton extends JButton {
    private final float lineSpacing;

    public LineHeightButton(String text, float lineSpacing) {
        super();
        this.lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
        setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setFont(getFont());
        String[] lines = getText().split("\n");
        int y = getInsets().top;
        for (String line : lines) {
            g2.drawString(line, getInsets().left, y += g2.getFontMetrics().getHeight() * lineSpacing);
        }
    }
}


Thank you very much. I added a modified version of your code to my question fixing the text's overprinting.
